# Selenium(with python): How to enter any text into wiki textarea

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textarea

I have one question on Selenium which is how can I enter text into textarea (wiki textarea)? Below is my original HTML, please help me to figure out this. Thank you very much!

```html
<textarea class="textarea long-field wiki-textfield mentionable wiki-editor-initialised wiki-edit-wrapped" cols="60" id="comment" name="comment" wrap="virtual" data-projectkey="PE15" data-issuekey="PE15-2181" resolved="" style="min-height: 174px; max-height: 369px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of selenium ? If not please go ahead and read it, because this is one of the most basic things selenium is capable of.

Comment: Hi,
I of course try the basic way but it seems not working so that I go here to ask answer. I think the reason is the text I faced is not normal textarea. This is Wiki textarea.

Answer (score 0):

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('comment')
text_area.send_keys("This text is send using Python code.")
```

Comment: Hi, 
This is the script I wrote, but is not working.. The element can not be find.

Comment: Try using wait methods.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided to send character sequence into the text area you need to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.textarea.long-field.wiki-textfield.mentionable.wiki-editor-initialised.wiki-edit-wrapped#comment"))).send_keys("Ben_C")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='textarea long-field wiki-textfield mentionable wiki-editor-initialised wiki-edit-wrapped' and @id='comment']"))).send_keys("Ben_C")
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```